# Can't get pyspark job to run on all nodes of hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

**Summary**: I can't get my python-spark job to run on **all** nodes of my hadoop cluster.
I've installed the spark for hadoop 'spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6'. When launching a java spark job, the load gets
distributed over all nodes, when launching a python spark job, only the one node takes the load.

**Setup**:

- hdfs and yarn configured for 4 nodes: nk01 (namenode), nk02, nk03, nk04, running on xen virtual servers
- versions: jdk1.8.0_66, hadoop-2.7.1, spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6
- hadoop installed all 4 nodes
- spark only installed on nk01

I copied a bunch of Gutenberg files (thank you, Johannes!) onto hdfs, and try doing a wordcount using java and python  on a subset of the files (the files that start with an 'e') :

**Python**:

Using a homebrew python script for doing wordcount:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit wordcount.py --master yarn-cluster \
    --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 1
```

The Python code assigns 4 partions:

```
tt=sc.textFile('/user/me/gutenberg/text/e*.txt',4)
```

Load on the 4 nodes during 60 seconds:

[image: load]

**Java**:

Using the **JavaWordCount** found in the spark distribution:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class JavaWordCount --master yarn-cluster \
    --num-executors 4 jwc.jar '/user/me/gutenberg/text/e*.txt'
```

[image: load]

**Conclusion**: the java version distributes its load across the cluster, the python version just runs on 1 node.

**Question**: how do I get the python version also to distribute the load across all nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark-submit

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class>
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

Here are some different with scala/java submit in parameter position.

> For Python applications, simply pass a .py file in the place of
>   **application-jar** instead of a JAR, and add Python .zip, .egg or .py files to the search path with --py-files.

You should use below command instead:
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster **wordcount.py**
    --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 1

Answer (score 5):

The python-program name was indeed in the wrong position, as suggested by Shawn Guo. It should have been run this way:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 4 
       --executor-cores 1 wordcount.py
```

That gives this load on the nodes: 
[image]