# how to properly submit spark job on yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to use the mllib in pyspark 
for example,

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector
```

If the job is submitted using yarn-client mode, everything works fine but not when it is submitted using yarn-cluster mode

I have tried submitting with --py-files $SPARK_HOME/python/lib/pyspark.zip but does not help.

The error message is exception from container launch exit code 1
what could be potential issues??

Comment: What is the exact command you entered?
Remember: spark-submit is finicky about the order of (some) parameters.
Eg. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310174/cant-get-pyspark-job-to-run-on-all-nodes-of-hadoop-cluster/34314942#34314942

Comment: it seems like it has to do with the cluster mode, worked in yarn-client but not cluster:  spark-submit --master yarn-cluster logistic_regression.py file://$SPARK_HOME/data/mllib/lr_data.txt 10

Comment: OK so I managed to find the log and seems like this is the cause: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logistic_regression.py", line 29, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: @ayin were you by any chance able to resolve this issue?